# GWT like perfect caching for non-GWT resources

Tags: caching, gwt, maven-2

## Perfect Caching

*Perfect Caching* allows the browser to cache resources forever and guarantees that changed resources are propagated immediately to the browser. In GWT this is accomplished by naming a file like the hash code of its content. As this leads to a new file name each time the content of a file changes, the browser can cache these files forever without having to ask the server whether or not there is a new version available. More about perfect caching can be found [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/2.3/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#perfect_caching).

As this concept works very well I would like to apply it to all of my non-GWT resources (some JS, CSS and image files).

As my build process is Maven based it would be great if there was a plugin which could automatically rename the files according to their hash code and which could adjust all of the references to this file.

## Here's an example

### Renaming

- foo.css -> foo_39757cec04498955db62043f7ecfefc2.cache.css
- logo.png -> logo_35bcdbbabe1944afc75eeeb16f06d1ad.cache.png

### Update references in files

- Replace all occurances of "foo.css" by "foo_39757cec04498955db62043f7ecfefc2.cache.css"
- Replace all occurances of "logo.png" by "logo_35bcdbbabe1944afc75eeeb16f06d1ad.cache.png"

Does anybody know whether something like that already exists?

Many thanks in advance,
Michael

Comment: are you using client bundles?

Comment: Yes I'm using ClientBundles and they work like a charm, but I'm talking about resources which cannot be managed by GWT for various reasons.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Apache (httpd) you can setup [mod_pagespeed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/module.html) to do that. Since GWT does some of that stuff already, be careful to properly configure mod_pagespeed so that performance doesn't degrade.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that mod_pagespeed is capable of doing that. Unfortunately performance with mod_pagespeed enabled is worse than without, just as you predicted. The problem is that mod_pagespeed disables caching for the GWT permutation's main HTML file. Do you have any information about how to configure mod_pagespeed for GWT applications?

Comment: follow the documentation on configuring filters, start by turning off all of them, and then enabling one by one, measuring performance along the way. i'd also remove the mod_pagespeed cache dir, just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

mod_pagespeed indeed disables HTML caching by default, as typically HTML is dynamic.  However, you can override that behavior.

There is a new option in the most recent binary release (0.10.21.*) that provides the behavior you want: explicitly control of your HTML caching headers:

```
  ModPagespeedModifyCachingHeaders off
```

http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/install.html#ModifyCachingHeaders

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer to the original question.  I think you meant to add this in as a comment to the other answer (and it is a useful response!).

You might want to review the about page [ http://stackoverflow.com/about ] - the conversations here are not like your average forum.